# I am getting error, while moving files in r

Tags: r, file

I am trying to move some files from one location to another using below code:

```
#exclude files with name .maf
filez <- grep(list.files(path="."), pattern='.maf', invert=TRUE, value=TRUE) 
filez <- data.frame(filez)
#select files with sepcial chr at 14 & 15 position in file name
Tumor <- filez %>% filter(between(as.integer(substr(filez, 14, 15)), 01, 09)) 
dir.create("Tumor")
file.move(Tumor$filez, "Tumor")
```

However I getting error

```
file.move(Tumor$filez, "Tumor")
Error in argchk_move_files(files = files, destinations = destinations,  : 
  Assertion on 'files' failed: Must be of type 'character', not 'factor'.
```

I donot know why error is coming.

Comment: Looks like your data frame is turning your character vector into a factor, which shouldn't happen with the latest version of R. What version of R is this? Why make a data frame anyway, you can just subset the vector? `filez=list.files(...)`  then `filez=files[some condition]`

Comment: THank you sir. My r version is 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

Comment: That's a very old version of R and if you upgrade to the latest (4.1.something) lots of problems will disappear.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for bringing your kind attention. I installed everything day before yesterday and since then facing lots of problem. I updated r from 3.6 to 4.1 and problem is disappeared. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up some files in a folder to illustrate:

```
> list.files(".")
[1] "abc01.maf" "abc02.maf" "abc03.maf" "abc04.maf" "abc05.maf" "abc06.maf"
[7] "abc07.maf"
```

Get some files into a vector (this is a bit different to you because I think you are getting all files that aren't `.maf` but this is close enough):

```
> filez <- grep(list.files(path="."), pattern='.maf', value=TRUE)
> filez
[1] "abc01.maf" "abc02.maf" "abc03.maf" "abc04.maf" "abc05.maf" "abc06.maf"
[7] "abc07.maf"
```

Now subset that vector using the condition derived from the numeric value in positions 4 and 5 being between 3 and 6:

```
> filez[dplyr::between(as.integer(substr(filez, 4,5)), 3, 6)]
[1] "abc03.maf" "abc04.maf" "abc05.maf" "abc06.maf"
```

Done. No need to create a data frame or use `filter`.

Comment: Thanks you for your kind help. You are doing right but whenevry I try file.move(Filez, "Tumor") it also showing same error in my system "Error in argchk_move_files(files = files, destinations = destinations,  : 
  Assertion on 'files' failed: No file provided." My r version is 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

Comment: class(filez) returns 
[1] "character"